# How to get this output in local

Tags: hadoop

hdfs dfs -ls -R hdfs:///data/msd > msd_filename.txt.

how to get the text file at local

hdfs dfs -ls -R hdfs:///data/msd > msd_filename.txt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want to copy a file from hdfs to your local directory. This command should help you:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path
```